# Pass Value From GridView to another

Tags: vb.net

How to change DataGridView in this code with GridView Dev Express ..

```
        For I = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
         DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
         DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(1).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name1")
         DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(2).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name2")
         DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(3).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name3")
         DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name4")
         DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(5).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name5")
Next
```

Comment: Hello & Welcome to SO, actually it is not clear what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T478919/gridcontrol-how-to-get-a-cell-value-from-the-selected-rows

Comment: I tried like this but not best result           For I = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
                Form1.GridView1.AddNewRow()
                Dim selectedRows() As Integer = GridView1.GetSelectedRows()
                For Each rowHandle As Integer In selectedRows
                    If rowHandle >= 0 Then
                        Dim cellValue1 = Form1.GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, 0) = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name1")
                        Dim cellValue2 = Form1.GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, 1) = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name2")
End If
                Next rowHandle

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that both of the grid controls you refer to should [have] be[en] used like this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DT

devExpressGridView.DataSource = DT
```

Comment: For I = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
           GridView1.AddNewRow()
           GridView1.SetRowCellValue(I).Item(1).value = DT.Rows(I)("Name1")
           GridView1.SetRowCellValue(I).Item(1).Value = DT.Rows(I)("Name2")
           GridView1.SetRowCellValue(I).Cells(2).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name3")
           GridView1.SetRowCellValue(I).Cells(3).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name4")
           GridView1.SetRowCellValue(I).Cells(4).Value = DT.Rows(I).Item("Name5")
        Next